# Getting data from fetch and not storing it in state

Tags: reactjs, fetch, redux

We have a React/Redux application where you can change language of the application and get all the strings for it from the API with fetch. Storing all the strings in the state seems like a bad idea, storing only the language (en, es, etc.) in state and strings elsewhere seems like a better one.

So is there a way to save data fetched in action from API call and not save it in state?

Comment: You have entire control over requests, maybe you'll just use something like `fetch(myRequestParams).then(fetchRes => filterData(fetchRes))` and use result from this kind of promise? How do you approach server requests?

Comment: Requests are done using isomorphic-fetch library. And in filterData(fetchRes) save it in global that I can access data anywhere?

Comment: But how do you fire requests themselves? I mean, do you fire requests on react component lifecycle hooks, use thunk-middleware or any other kind of things? There's no `the only right` thing to do and you have all the options of shaping results of api requests and storing them in your app state tree (or not storing) as you need to.

Comment: Actually both, on componentWillMount I load the default language strings (or preferred one from previous login) or firing an async action using thunk middleware when user wants to change the language and save received data in state.

Comment: So why don't put filtering code into this thunk function? You can fire request, gather data, filter it and only then dispatch action to your store.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the store then you should not use an action to fetch for the data.

You could store the translation somewhere else and just reference them from the state. If you decide to go down this route, the easiest option is not to use the store and fetch the translation outside of redux (i.e. no action).

The other option is to store the translations in the state. You might not like it, but it's perfectly viable. Storing all the state in one single object has its benefits (time travel, debugging, etc.).

I don't think there's a clear cut in this scenario.

Also, there's an [interesting discussion about storing all or partial state in the store](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/1385) on Github.

Comment: Storing all of the translations in the state, kind of breaks the Redux idea of having the smallest state as possible. What about wrapping components with higher order component and provide translations in context? Is there a way then that I can change the context itself from an action?

Comment: I think you're right. Redux is about storing state, not data. However, you could store the language selection in the store (i.e. `{..., language: 'en_EN'}`). When you render the component you could reference the external translation object `myTranslationObj[this.props.language].title`. So the context is saved in the store, because it turns out to be *real* state.